# Standardize search results

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search

I have been using search frequently over the past couple of days and have some suggestions for improvements.

When I search for a tag like this

> [jquery]

I get the following:

- Search box is cleared and the words search appear, this means I have to retype [jquery] again if I need to refine my search
- The number of questions that match the search are shown
- The words "40,227 questions tagged" is displayed
- Search tips not displayed

When I search in combination with a tag like this

> [jquery] hasaccepted:1

I get the following:

- Search terms are displayed in the search box so that I can further refine my search
- The number of questions that match the search are not show
- The words "posts containing hasaccepted:1 within these tags"
- Search tips displayed

Spot the difference...

- In first case have to retype query terms in search box
- In first case matching number is displayed
- In first case questions are referred to as questions, in the second case as posts
- In the second case search tips are displayed

I know this is mainly due to status by design, but I quite often search for the tag first and then want to refine that search after wards. It would also be great to see the matching count.

[Search for jquery tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery)

[Search for jquery tag with hasaccepted](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[jquery]+hasaccepted%3A1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all of the above concerns should be addressed now:

- the tag pages will populate their tags in the search box for easy refinement

  - the search page will leave the search box alone as well
- search pages will now have a result count (this goes out tonight)
- the advanced options are split into their own little section on the right now

One item won't be addressed though:

- In first case questions are referred to as questions, in the second case as posts

Search can return both questions *and* answers (unlike a "questions tagged" page), so we'll continue to use the all-inclusive "post" label (like on [the /search help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search)) when this is the case.